# Changing from c++ to perl

Tags: c++, perl

I have unusual problem, there's no perl chat room so i decided to ask little questions here.

```
 #include <cstdio> 

 double end, tmp; 
 int test; 

 int main(void) {
     scanf("%d", &test);
     for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
         scanf("%*s%*s%lf", &tmp);
         end += tmp;
     }
     end /= (double)test;
     printf("%.2lf", end); 
     return 0;
 }
```

I have this little C++ code.
How to write in Perl something like this ? I mean how to read string and ignore it and how to read double numbers and output them.

Comment: "chat room":  #perl-help on MagNET  `irc://irc.perl.org/perl-help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is roughly equivalent to yours:

```
my $divisor = <STDIN>;
chomp $divisor;

my $dividend = 0;

while (<STDIN>) {
  my ($ignore1, $ignore2, $term) = split;
  chomp $term;
  $dividend += $term;
}

print( ($dividend / $divisor) . $/ );
```

It of course doesn't check for proper input, divide by zero or anything like that, but neither does the original code.